# Angular, MYSQL, PHP Store Image

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to store images from a `<input type='file'>` into Mysql.

We can start a whole discussion about storing binary data in a database or just the path to the file, but i chose this way because it will make the backup much easier :)

this is my code so far:

Controller:

```
JourneyFactory.StoreJourney(this.journey)
            .success(function(data){
                journeyStatus = data;
            });
```

Factory:

```
        StoreJourney: function(journey){
        var params = {
            action : 'store',
            journey: journey
        };

        return $http({
            url    : '../server/journey.php',
            method : 'GET',
            params : params
        });
```

journey.php:

```
//omitted not relevant code

 private function Store($journey){

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $journey->PriceValid = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($journey->PriceValid));

    if($this->database->Insert("INSERT INTO journey (ID, Name, Code, Country, Price, PriceValid, Thumb, Image, Description) VALUES (:ID, :Name, :Code, :Country, :Price, :PriceValid, :Thumb, :Image, :Description)", $journey)){
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
    }
}
```

database.php:

```
public function Insert($query, $params){
    $connection = $this->OpenConnection();
    $query      = $connection->prepare($query);

    try{

        foreach($params as $key => $value){
            if($key == 'Image' || $key == 'Thumb'){
                $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            }else{
                $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
            }
        };

        $query->execute();

        return true;

    }catch (PDOException $ex){
        echo 'Query failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }finally{
        $this->CloseConnection($connection);
    }

    return false;
}
```

It inserts every value as it should be in the database except for the 2 images.. only a small part gets stored:

```
433A5C66616B65706174685C646F776E6C6F61642E706E67
```

(the same for both images even though it are 2 different files) Headers maybe ??

Any idea how to get this working?

**EDIT:**

Mysql:

Column data type: `MEDIUMBLOB`

Changing to POST doesn't change anything

thanks for your time,

Comment: What is the type/size of your image field in the DB? And note that file upload should be using POST. `GET` is general limited in length and WILL truncate a "large" upload.

Comment: The data type of the field is MEDIUMBLOB, I'm going try to change it to POST now, thanks for the tip

Comment: I switched to POST without any success, the same problem :(